# How to highlight the active menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="label") {echo 'class="active"';}?>></li>
```

It get highlighted if the url like this(http://example.com/label)

if URL like this means (http://example.com/label/view/2) it become inactive. how to add class active in both case

Comment: what `$this->uri->segment(1)` prints in your second case?

Comment: It print as label.

Comment: then this code should work, if `$this->uri->segment(1)` prints `label` then your condition is met and class should be add there. Try to check what `var_dump($this->uri->segment(1)=="label")` prints

Comment: please post some code where you are having trouble, please.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before so here's the the solution that I did. For Example you got this kind of URL
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up

The segment numbers would be this:

1.news
2.local
3.metro
4.crime_is_up

reference:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri

So in your case

label/view/2" uri->segment(3)=="menu_name"){echo 'class="active"';}?> view

The menu_name is the name of the page you want to active.

I hope it helps.